# How to use a specific comparer func for Equality in FluentAssertions

Tags: c#, akka.net, fluent-assertions

I'm writing an Akka.NET Testkit implementation that uses FluentAssertions under the hood, but can't figure out how to write the 'last' Assertion: Equality using a custom Func equality comparer (while getting a nice Error message, of course).

```
public void AssertEqual<T>(T expected, T actual,
                           Func<T, T, bool> comparer,
                           string format = "", params object[] args)
{
    // This works, but does not give a good message:
    comparer(expected, actual).Should().BeTrue(format, args);

    // But this doesn't work at all:
    // actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => 
             options.Using<T>( x => comparer(x.Subject, expected).Should().BeTrue())
             .WhenTypeIs<T>(),
         format, args);
}
```

I'm pretty sure there must be some fancy way in FA to do this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you replace the call to `BeEquivalentTo` with a custom assertion built on top of `Execute.Assertion` as documented in the [extensibility section](https://fluentassertions.com/extensibility/#building-your-own-extensions)?

Or just use `BeEquivalentTo` directly using its options? You can even wrap it in your own code like this:

```
public static void AssertEqual<T>(T actual, T expected,
    Func<EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>, EquivalencyAssertionOptions<T>> config)
{
    Func<EquivalencyAssertionOptions<TEvent>, EquivalencyAssertionOptions<TEvent>> effectiveConfig = opt =>
    {
        // customize the assertion in addition to the caller's customization

        return config(opt);
    };

    actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, effectiveConfig);
}
```

Comment: So could I go with just calling Execute.Assertion (I'm implementing a set of Akka TestKit custom assertions - there is no point in making the implementation reusable.
```public void AssertEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, Func<T, T, bool> comparer, string format = "", params object[] args)
        {
            Execute.Assertion
                .BecauseOf(format, args)
                .ForCondition(comparer(expected, actual))
                .FailWith($"{typeof(T).Name} was expected to be equal to `{expected}` (using a custom comparison), but was `{actual}` instead");
        }```

Comment: If you wrap the `Func` with an `Expression`, FA will format it into something readable (mostly).

Comment: Exactly what my colleague https://stackoverflow.com/users/74198/bas-bossink suggested indeed. I'll try!